# How to change type/class of each matrix in list of matrices without losing matrix structure

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of matrices, for example:

```
cdf
[[1]]
      [,1]  [,2] 
 [1,] "361" "403"
 [2,] "332" "450"
 [3,] "346" "444"
 [4,] "364" "415"
```

Using `lapply(cdf, as.numeric)` returns each matrix as a numeric vector:

```
[[1]]
 [1] 361 332 346 364 367 402 722 415
```

What function can I use to convert the matrices to numeric without losing the matrix structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```r
lapply(cdf, function(x) `storage.mode<-`(x, "numeric"))
```

In essence, when you call `as.numeric` you change the storage mode, which is `character`, and class, which is `matrix`. To just change the storage mode, and retain the class, you can use `storage.mode(x) <- "numeric"` or the function `storage.mode<-` (or `mode<-`). Just make sure you put backticks around it.

You can read the details in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works. "storage.mode"? Never seen it before, anyway thanks.

Comment: @Peter.k you can read about it in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html). You can also use `mode<-` if you want to keep things short (I just updated the answer).